# Kosi Bay border crossing from South Africa to Mozambique

Tags: borders, mozambique

I will be crossing the Kosi Bay border from the South African side on 25 December 2018. Has anybody experience crossing this border over the festive period?

- How long did it take?
- Were people queuing and waiting in an orderly fashion?

I have crossed this border before, just not over the festive period. It was relatively well run and efficient, and I was able to cross within 45 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

I crossed the border on the 26 November from Kosi Bay to Moz and it took me 20 minutes. I asked the border control  officials what the situation would be in December.

There will be staff reinforcements for the festive season.
There are renovations currently in place to insure smooth running of the border.

I am sure you won't encounter problems; Mozambique has a new road system from the border inland. This enables traffic to move faster.